# IPA Processing Failed when Arching Project using Xcode 11

Tags: xcode, ios13, ipa, xcode11

I have been trying to archive a project of mine and cannot get it to work. I have looked at other suggestions including, removing x86_64 and i386 from frameworks to no avail and I have messed with all of the build setting/phases. 
My project is not using Carthage just Cocoa Pods and they are all up to date. 
When it fails to archive I clicked "Show Logs" and at the very bottom it says the following:

```
alerts =     (
            {
        code = 3620;
        description = "Configuration issue: platform AppleTVSimulator.platform doesn't have any non-simulator SDKs; ignoring it";
        info =             {
        };
        level = WARN;
    },
            {
        code = 3620;
        description = "Configuration issue: platform WatchSimulator.platform doesn't have any non-simulator SDKs; ignoring it";
        info =             {
        };
        level = WARN;
    },
            {
        code = 3620;
        description = "Configuration issue: platform iPhoneSimulator.platform doesn't have any non-simulator SDKs; ignoring it";
        info =             {
        };
        level = WARN;
    }
);
```

UPDATE: I don't think it is a framework issue as another application I have uses the same frameworks and archives fine.

Comment: Do you have any other information? Like the error that's shown? These logs only contain warnings so that shouldn't cause failures.

Comment: @donnywals I don't have anything else, i don't get an error in the console, just a screen that says IPA Processing Failed and the only options from there are Cancel and Show Logs, and the code I pasted is what it says in those logs.

Comment: compare project settings on project that fails and one that succeeds, something is different.

Comment: @KirilS. They're the same on both, just double checked.

Comment: See the answer below. It works. Weird and messed up, but functional.

Answer (score 8):

I had the very same issue 'IPA processing failed' along with these warning.. Current workaround is to press enter as soon as the App thinning window appears while archiving, as the “Next” button has the focus, or being super fast clicking on it.

And make sure to "Uncheck" the bitcode check while creating the IPA.

Comment: Okay, seriously, this WORKS. I don't know why, I don't know how, (I don't wanna know) but it does. No issues with the distribution at all. App runs perfectly.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly! It's crazy that this is the correct solution.